# Access 2010 -- query to determine inclusion in date range

Tags: sql, ms-access, ms-access-2010

I am a newbie to both SQL and Access and was wondering if you could help please?

I am in the process of creating a hotel bookings database using Access 2010 but I cannot get my query working where I search for a vacant room.

My database has 5 tables as follows (Field Names in brackets):

```
BOOKINGS (BookRef, CustAcctNo, BookDate, ArrivDate, DurStay, EmpNo, RoomNo)
CUSTOMERS (CustAcctNo, Title, Forename, Surname, Address1, Address2, Address3)
EMPLOYEES (EmpNo, Title, Forename, Surname)
ROOM TYPES (RoomType, Description, Rate/Price)
ROOMS (RoomNo, RoomType)
```

These tables all have a 'one-to-many' relationship i.e. one customer can have many bookings.

So, my thinking is that the Fields of interest would be the ArrivDate Field (date of arrival) and DurStay (Duration of Stay) Field. In the Rooms table the Room Number is the Field I am calling out.

So, the closest I have got so far is the following:

```
PARAMETERS [Start Date] DateTime, [End Date] DateTime;
SELECT R.*, [Start Date] AS Expr1, [End Date] AS Expr2, *
FROM ROOMS AS R 
    LEFT JOIN (SELECT B.RoomNo 
    FROM Bookings AS B 
    WHERE ([Start Date] between B.ArrivDate and (B.ArrivDate + [Please Enter]))  
        AND ([End Date] between B.ArrivDate and (B.ArrivDate + B.DURSTAY))) AS BKD 
    ON R.RoomNo = BKD.RoomNo
    WHERE (((BKD.RoomNo) Is Null));
```

This just doesn't seem to be working for me at all. I have tried many times with different versions of the above code but seem to be getting nowhere. My thoughts were that I do a search where the field is null between the dates plus the duration of stay but maybe I am going about it the wrong way I am not sure.

Hopefully I have provided enough detail here but please let me know if you need to know more. I really appreciate you all having a look at this at least. Maybe a fresh outlook on it might spot where I am going wrong.

Many thanks in advance for any help you can offer.

Comment: What precisely is wrong with the result of your query?

Comment: Using the code formatting for the SQL in your question will likely result in more people attempting to answer. Also when you say "This just doesn't seem to be working for me at all." specifically *what* is not working? What do you expect to happen vs what is actually happening?

Comment: Sorry Guys, What the query is doing is bringing me back results that are incorrect i.e. Room 2 has a booking of 04/08/2014 for a duration of 7 days. So, when the query is ran for parameter dates between 07/08/2014 and 14/08/2014 Room 2 is being returned when it shouldn't be as it is not vacant during the dates of the parameter.

Answer (score 0):

Try changing from this:

```
WHERE ([Start Date] between B.ArrivDate and ... 
    AND ([End Date] between B.ArrivDate and ...
```

to this:

```
WHERE ([Start Date] between B.ArrivDate and ... 
    OR ([End Date] between B.ArrivDate and ...
```

I think this fulfills the logic better because it accepts a partial match, that is, an overlap in dates.

Comment: Hi Smandoli, Thank you so much for your prompt response. I think that has done the trick. I cannot thank you enough. I will run a few tests here and mark this as the solution but the few tests I have ran so far are looking good. Thank you, I really appreciate your help.

Comment: Sorry Smandoli, After some more testing, I am afraid it isn't working. I have ran a few tests and some rooms are still showing as vacant when they are not vacant. On one test for example Room 12 had an arrival date of 10/09/2014 and duration of stay was 3 days. When I ran the query Start Date 01/09/2014 and End Date 14/09/2014 it said the room was vacant during that period. I am 'almost' there. I think the last piece of the jigsaw might be the way the current arrival dates plus the duration of stay are being treated but can't seem to put my finger on it.

Comment: Thanks for update.  Calculating dates can be tricky.  It may help to post the data for Room 12.  I trust your date fields are set as date format in the table.

Comment: Of course you must run a query that includes `B.ArrivDate + B.DURSTAY AS EndDateTest`, so you can ensure the desired result.

Comment: Hello Smandoli, Thank you for your reply. Yes, I do have the date fields as date format. Here is the data for Room 12: 3 bookings including Booking 1: ArrivDate 10/09/2014 DurStay 3 nights, Booking 2: ArrivDate 18/07/2014 DurStay 7 nights and Booking 3: ArrivDate 07/07/2014 DurStay 10 nights.

Comment: I have uploaded the database itself to Dropbox if it helps. Here is the link: https://www.dropbox.com/s/3o0ktcacy7nu8l1/Hotel%20Database.accdb There are a few queries in there but the one I am working on is qryVacantRooms. Thanks again.

Answer (score 0):

```
PARAMETERS [Start Date] DateTime, [End Date] DateTime;
SELECT R.*, [Start Date] AS Expr1, [End Date] AS Expr2, *
FROM ROOMS AS R 
    LEFT JOIN (SELECT B.RoomNo 
    FROM Bookings AS B 
    WHERE ([Start Date] between B.ArrivDate and (B.ArrivDate + **B.DURSTAY**))  
        **OR** ([End Date] between B.ArrivDate and (B.ArrivDate + B.DURSTAY))) AS BKD 
    ON R.RoomNo = BKD.RoomNo
    WHERE (((BKD.RoomNo) Is Null));
```

or
an easier, more elegant query would be something like:

```
SELECT R.*, #06/05/2014# as [Start Date] , #06/10/2014# as [End Date] 
FROM ROOMS AS R    
WHERE R.RoomNo not in 
(
SELECT DISTINCT RoomNo FROM Bookings B
    WHERE (#06/05/2014# between B.Arrival and (B.Arrival + B.Duration))  
        OR (#06/10/2014# between B.Arrival and (B.Arrival + B.Duration)) 
);
```

The date parameters must be passed in the american format (#MM/DD/YYYY#)